# updates HumanResources.Employee table 'column SickLeave Hours' 10 rows at a time (allow the batch size to be variable)

Tags: t-sql

updates HumanResources.Employee table 'column SickLeave Hours'

I need to do the following logic:
if Hours greater than or equal to 35 set to 40
if less than 35 set it to 0.
How to break the loop?

How can I achieve this in SQL Server?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your exact column name is but maybe you want something like:

```
DECLARE @BatchSize int
SET @BatchSize = 10
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
   UPDATE TOP (@BatchSize) HumanResource.Employee
     SET SickLeaveHours = CASE WHEN SickLeaveHours >= 35 THEN 40 ELSE 0 END
   WHERE SickLeaveHours NOT IN (40,0)
END
```